# USA Residential Electricity Prices

Tags: data-request, usa, historical, time-series, energy

**EDITED QUESTION to add context:**

I'm interested in "modeling" the Electricity Price for Residential Users in the US, particularly (if possible) in Massachusetts.

I'd like to obtain something like a 24 hourly-prices list for every day of the year.

To relax this constraint, I could also accept a list of 24 hourly-prices per month, or even just per season.

And, to relax even more, I could also accept a resolution greater than 1 hour.
E.g.: resolution = 4 hours:
so, instead of having a price for each hour of the day, I could accept a single price for an interval of 4 hours (so 6 prices per day).

So, I'm looking for something similar to the dataset of this link: https://data.open-power-system-data.org/time_series/2020-10-06.
It consists of a CSV file which collects hourly electricity prices 32 European countries, but I'm interested in the US.

Another way could also be to find scientific papers (or other sources) which model the electricity price associated to every hour of the day (this time interval could be relaxed) in the US as a PDF, by providing the 'mean' and the 'standard deviation' (or any other parameter which describe the PDF).

Is there anyone who knows any reference (papers, dataset, link, ...) which could be useful?

Comment: with some exceptions, residential customers don't usually pay an hourly "spot" price, but rather a fixed tariff based on the peak/non-peak hour of the day and day of the week.

Comment: Thank you all! I edited my question to add some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest you can get is a monthly average retail price. The Energy Information Agency provides a monthly report on [average retail price of electricity](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/browser/#/topic/7?agg=0,1&geo=002&endsec=8&linechart=ELEC.PRICE.MA-RES.M&columnchart=ELEC.PRICE.MA-RES.M&map=ELEC.PRICE.MA-RES.M&freq=M&start=200101&end=202102&ctype=linechart&ltype=pin&rtype=s&maptype=0&rse=0&pin=) by state (note that EIA [has an API](https://www.eia.gov/opendata/) if you want to access this data programmatically):

[image: Average retail price of electricity, monthly: Massachusetts residential]

As mentioned in the comments, it's unlikely that any significant amount of residential customers in Massachusetts are on a rate that would change during the course of the day. To confirm, you could [get a list of Massachusetts utilities (xlsx)](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/sales_revenue_price/xls/table6.xlsx) from EIA, then check their rates at [USURDB](https://openei.org/apps/USURDB/). I spot checked and see that there are a few optional TOU rates at a couple of the larger utilities. However, according to [this 2017 study](http://files.brattle.com/files/12658_the_national_landscape_of_residential_tou_rates_a_preliminary_summary.pdf), only about 3% of customers are using TOU rates where they are offered.